# Cannot set AutoDeleteOnIdle in IBus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint

Tags: masstransit

When using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus and the `IBus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint`, there doesn't seem to be a way to make an auto-created subscription temporary or short-lived.  The queue will be temporary, but not the subscription.  The queue will have a short `AutoDeleteOnIdle` value, but the subscription will have a very large value.

If you pass in a `TemporaryEndpointDefinition` then MassTransit will give the queue a 5 minute AutoDeleteOnIdle, but the subscription will be set to over a year.  If, instead, you try to configure the `AutoDeleteOnIdle` value from within `IBus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint` then you're given an error that a value is being set on a property that has already been used.

I've seen in some other answers that claim that Azure Service Bus subscriptions have a bug where they don't auto-delete if they have a Forward Rule set.  However, I'm not sure if it's even being given a chance since the AutoDeleteOnIdle is set to such a high value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug/limitation/defect/whatever in Azure Service Bus as it relates to topic subscriptions created with AutoDeleteOnIdle that ForwardTo another messaging entity. They will *never* be set to AutoDeleteOnIdle, nor will they ever AutoDeleteOnIdle.

For these temporary endpoints, it is better to use `ISubscriptionEndpointConnector` and create a subscription on the topic of interest and set it to AutoDeleteOnIdle. That way, things work as expected and the subscription will automatically cleanup.

The other option is to specify `RemoveSubscriptions` when configuring the receive endpoint, and when the bus is stopped, MassTransit will explicitly remove the subscription upon successful bus shutdown.

Comment: I'll take `ISubscriptionEndpointConnector` approach, instead.  Thanks! I should note, though, that after MassTransit creates the Subscription/Queue, I am able to manually change the Subscription configuration to set an AutoDeleteOnIdle value through the Azure portal or through client tools.  So maybe that bug was fixed at some point?

Comment: You're able to change it, but does it actually delete itself?